# Facebook getAccessToken() returns app access token: works fine in one server but throws app access token in other.

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook getAccessToken() returns app access token: works fine in one server but throws app access token in other. 
I have tried all the answers given in previous such questions. But doesn't seem to work.

```
<code>
$acces_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
print_r($acces_token);

output:
app ID | app secret 
</code>
```

The funny part here is the same code works in localhost and one of my servers. I recently got another server, and this thing doesn't work in this server.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is, when user comes to the site, I check if he has accepted the app, if yes then I get the access token, at this point I do  $facebook->getuser() and check in my DB that if the [id] is in my DB if yes then login if not then create a user in DB. Since FB is throwing me App Access token FB-> getuser gives me nothing. and I get DB insert error because there is nothing to put inside or check if the user is in or not.

Comment: One more thing I want to add is this same piece of code works on one server and this on another. both the servers has different domain names, but I think this doesn't matter because I removed the one working and kept the only which wasn't working. but same thing....

Comment: As you are getting APP Access Token, it might reflect that the user has not authorized your application, also as one of your server is working and not the other I would like to suggest you to recheck the App Settings to check if you have the settings right. `getUser()` function returns when there is user present so just double check if you are getting the authorization part correct. Although there might be some issue with server, there was an question about app not working on one server but working on other earlier also on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This happens after user accepts my permissions. one more thing I realized that with my account 50% of time I get correct access token. And for some users not at all. And I checked that other post and tried everything. I even messed with base_facebook.php but the <code> getAccessTokenFromCode()</code> is the only method which creates accessToken. About the app settings, I created another app with this server and still the same problem. Its so strange that same piece of code works in one and not in another server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, turns out I didn't have the "fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt" file included (and I had the same problem before, the .crt was out of date) (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src). So this may be the issue, and it wasn't documented in their instructions, so both times took me a while to figure out.